# Unsuccessful with GDB and Info Reg Command. Can't seem to find the ebp, eip and esp values

Tags: linux, gdb, overflow, buffer, eip

I'm having a problem with GDB. I'm studying buffer overflow right now and I need to run the command `$Info reg` to find information about `ebp`, `eip` and `esp` but I get no results from any of them. I tried out `Info reg $name` with each one of them but only `ebp` works.

Basicly this is what happens:

```
(gdb) i r
rax            0x7fffffffe180   140737488347520

rbx            0x0  0

rcx            0x7fffffffe570   140737488348528

rdx            0x7fffffffe1a6   140737488347558

rsi            0x6  6

...

...

...



es             0x0  0

fs             0x0  0

---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---+

gs             0x0  0
```

and

```
(gdb) info reg $ebp

ebp            0x41414141   1094795585
```

but

```
(gdb) info reg $eip

Invalid register `eip'
```

How can I get the values to these parts of memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no reg called `eip` in amd64 arch

let me show what is `bp`/`ebp`/`rbp`, a data register contains 64 bits on amd64 arch:

```
64 ---------------------------- 32 ---------- 16 ---- 8 ---- 0
| <--------------------------- rbp ------------------------> |
                                 | <--------- ebp ---------> |
                                               | <--- bp --> |
```

so you can access corresponding bits by different name.

but you always access `rip` as a whole word, because there is no reason to access the lower bits of `instruction pointer`, as a result, there aro no `eip`/`ip` registers in amd64 arch

Comment: I haven't studied all the 64-bit stuff yet, but in i386 `bh` and `bl` are parts of `bx`, not `bp`. I'd be surprised if they changed that in amd64.